# How to parse data stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a CSV file I am working with. I don't want to convert it to an object to have keys and values. I want to be able to create more arrays to store different values
I.e Temperature
Hum
hours
snowDepth etc
All these will be arrays with 7 values

Right now, this is how the csv is stored in the data array

> 1. "11/28/2018 7:30,1128,-2.122,86.2,34.06,1.178,320.2,20.4"
>      ​
> 2. "11/28/2018 7:45,1129,-2.325,85.6,34.54,1.771,325.5,30.72"
>      ​
> 3. "11/28/2018 8:00,1130,-2.679,85.7,30.73,1.764,312.1,28.98"
>      ​
> 4. "11/28/2018 8:15,1131,-2.872,88,34.55,1.073,306.6,25.65"
>      ​
> 5. "11/28/2018 8:30,1132,-2.953,90.7,35.25,1.247,311.2,30.06"
>      ​
> 6. "11/28/2018 8:45,1133,-3.064,93.3,35,1.449,312.6,30.13"
>      ​
> 7. "11/28/2018 9:00,1134,-2.771,91.5,33.44,0.988,311,28.27"
>      ​
>      length: 7

the 1st col is the timestamp, 2nd is record number, 3rd is the temperature, 4th is the humidity and so on.

```
function get_Data(data) {
    "use strict";
    var fileData = new Array();
    data = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    data = data.slice(Math.max(data.length - 7, 0));
    createGraph(data);
}
```

I want arrays like this

Tem = [-2.122, -2.325, -2.679, -2.872 ...]

hours = [7:30, 7:45, 8:00, 8:15 ...]

Comment: You don't really have to parse anything. You just have to split by comma. To create an array of the values of column `i`: `values = arr.map(str => str.split(',')[i])`. Lots of related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+parse+csv

Comment: Could you add every value? We have the first four, but in each row there are eight values.

Comment: yeah, the 5th is SnowDepth, 6th is WS_ms_S_WVT(speed) 7th is WindDir_D1_WVT and 8th is the SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up a few things. What's `fileData` doing (seems unused)? And `slice` isn't the right way to do this.

Instead, try:

```
function get_Data(csv) {
    csv = csv.replace(/[\r\n]+/gi,"\n"); // reduce line endings into single LF chars
    rows = csv.split("\n"); // split into array of rows
    var result = [];
    for (var i in rows) result.push(rows[i].split(",")); // split each row
    return result;
}
```

(edit) If you only the need the last X rows of the CSV data, use:

```
function get_Data(csv,lastNumRows) { // get only the last <lastNumRows> rows
    csv = csv.replace(/[\r\n]+/gi,"\n"); // reduce line endings into single LF chars
    rows = csv.split("\n").slice(-lastNumRows); // split into array of rows
    var result = [];
    for (var i in rows) result.push(rows[i].split(",")); // split each row
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's true, I don't need the fileData. I wanted the last 7 rows of the file

Comment: Right, now I see how you used `slice`. I edited my answer for getting only the last 7 rows.

Comment: Oh but I also see I misread your original question, you actually need the columns (e.g. all temperatures or all humidities), not rows. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Simple - `map`  and `split` for each comma, then look at the index for which item it should be:

```js
var data = ["11/28/2018 7:30,1128,-2.122,86.2,34.06,1.178,320.2,20.4",
  "11/28/2018 7:45,1129,-2.325,85.6,34.54,1.771,325.5,30.72",
  "11/28/2018 8:00,1130,-2.679,85.7,30.73,1.764,312.1,28.98",
  "11/28/2018 8:15,1131,-2.872,88,34.55,1.073,306.6,25.65",
  "11/28/2018 8:30,1132,-2.953,90.7,35.25,1.247,311.2,30.06",
  "11/28/2018 8:45,1133,-3.064,93.3,35,1.449,312.6,30.13",
  "11/28/2018 9:00,1134,-2.771,91.5,33.44,0.988,311,28.27",
];

var items = {
  date: [],
  recordNumber: [],
  temperature: [],
  humidity: [],
  value5: [],
  value6: [],
  value7: [],
  value8: [],
};

Object.keys(items).forEach((key, index) => items[key].push(data.map(str => str.split(",")[index])));

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work. i know the position of the data so it was easy to split and find the terms and date

```js
var csv = document.getElementById("csvFile").innerHTML ;



function get_Data(data) {
    var result = {terms:[], hours:[] }
    var r = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);

    r.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element !== "" && element.length>1){
      var term = element.split(",")[2]
      var date = new Date(element.split(",")[0])
      var hour =  date.getHours() + ":" + (date.getMinutes()<=9 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes());
      
      result.terms.push(term);
      result.hours.push(hour)
      }
    });
 return result;
} 

console.log( get_Data(csv))
```

```html
<div id="csvFile" style="display:none;">
11/28/2018 7:30,1128,-2.122,86.2,34.06,1.178,320.2,20.4
11/28/2018 7:45,1129,-2.325,85.6,34.54,1.771,325.5,30.72
11/28/2018 8:00,1130,-2.679,85.7,30.73,1.764,312.1,28.98
11/28/2018 8:15,1131,-2.872,88,34.55,1.073,306.6,25.65
11/28/2018 8:30,1132,-2.953,90.7,35.25,1.247,311.2,30.06
11/28/2018 8:45,1133,-3.064,93.3,35,1.449,312.6,30.13
11/28/2018 9:00,1134,-2.771,91.5,33.44,0.988,311,28.27
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to do position because the records varies each time there is a new row. This will affect the values stored in an array. I don't know if that makes sense

Comment: hmm but @Jack Bashford did the same thing. my solution is like this becouse then you could control your data parsing. like hour for instead. but yah as you which